# backing up data from app engine datastore as spreadsheet or csv

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am making a survay website on google app engine using Python. For saving the survey form data i am using NDB Datastore. After the survey I have to import it as spreadsheet or CSV. How can i do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Stick to one question per question... nobody will answer all these questions at ones.. so I would suggest you to delete everything and leave only the relevant to exporting to CSV..

Comment: sorry, i have done that. need help on  this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at the google spreadsheets api, google it, try it, come back when something specific doesnt work.
Also consider using google forms instead which already do what you want (save responses to a spreadsheet)